# How to develop controller in Node.js Express with mssql

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, rest, express

I am building  rest api app using express.js and mssql module and I'm stacked with problem:
I need flexible architecture for my app. So I have this structure:

```
controller
--products.js
router
--api
---products.js
-settings.js
-app.js
```

In app.js I start express server, in router/api/products.js I set some api endpoints. But in controller I need to 
1) start connection
2) start request
3) add data to request from router 
And the problem is that in each file in controller I need to copy-paste same code as:

```
var sqlDb = require('mssql');
var settings = require('./settings');

exports.executeQuery = function (bdRole,sql,callback) {
    var config = [];
    switch(bdRole) {
        case 'Main' : config = settings.sqlDbConfigMain; break
        case 'Child' : config = settings.sqlDbConfigChild; break
        default : config = null;
    }
    var conn = new sqlDb.Connection(config);
    conn.connect()
        .then(function(){
            var req = new sqlDb.Request(conn);
            req.query(sql)
                .then(function (recordset) {
                    callback(recordset);

                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    callback(null,err);
                });

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(null,err);
        });
};
```

And I think that it is vary bad to copy-past code. But all my attempts to split this code to make its more flexible failed because I'm newbie.

I not found any examples which can help me(

I need not only execute query, but I need to execute procedure with table variable inside etc.

So the question is: Do I need to put the

```
var sqlDb = require('mssql');
var settings = require('./settings');
```

in each controller and continue copy-past or a more correct approach(way) exist?